# CSS-Like color classes in Photoshop or Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to define a color palette in Photoshop or Illustrator and use them as reference colors when filling objects? Sort of the behavior CSS classes have, where if you change a color in a CSS class, all tags with that class will be affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Illustrator at least, you can use the Swatches palette to save colours and make them 'global'. That means that if you redefine the swatch in the palette, anything that uses that swatch will change colour as well.

1. Create a colour in the colour picker or any other method you prefer;
2. Open the Swatches palette (<kbd>Window > Swatches</kbd>);
3. Click the <kbd>[+]</kbd> icon in the bottom right of the palette;
4. In the popup that appears, make sure to tick the 'Global' tickbox;
5. Apply the swatch to shapes by selecting stroke or fill in the toolbox and then single-clicking the swatch in the Swatches palette—do note it has a white corner in the thumbnail;
6. Double-click the global swatch in the Swatches palette to re-open the dialog box;
7. Change the swatch's colour composition and click OK.

Do note that a swatch has to be applied to an object after it has been made global in order to be still linked to the swatch and change along with it. If you apply a non-global swatch to an object, then make the swatch global and change its colour, the object will retain the original colour.

The same functionality has been requested in Photoshop as well, but as far as I know, it hasn't been implemented. [The feature-request thread here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-ideas/photoshop-supporting-global-color-on-the-swatches-panel/idi-p/12249294) might show some insight in the why.

Comment: I dont really see why a fill layer might not be linked since it represents a scene graph object. But in general it seems to me that Adobe really really wants to stop the idea of scene graph objects that users could remotely manipulate. The only software that does this badly is After effects. But in general PS is the lowest denominator and has least amount of scene graph to begin with. But the answer to why not is simply: Why do you expect a direct modeling tools to implement indirect modeling?